# Как добавить символ в начало определённых строк?

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, bash

Есть файл конфигурации, где есть определённый параметр.
Какими командами можно поставить и убрать в начале строки параметра знак # ?

Пример файла

```
# /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/program1 &
 /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/program2 &
# /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/program3 &

exit 0
```

Нужны две команды, одна убирает знак комментария у program3, другая добавляет знак комментария обратно.

Параметр program3 может находиться в любой по счёту строке
И если строка уже комментирована, то команда комментирования должна проигнорировать эту строку

Answer (score 11, accepted):

поставить символ `#` в начало строки, содержащей `текст`:

```
$ sed -i '/текст/s/^/#/' файл
```

убрать символы `#` в начале строки, содержащей `текст`:

```
$ sed -i '/текст/s/^#\+//' файл
```

поставить символ `#` в начало строки, содержащей `текст`, и начинающейся **не** с символа `#`:

```
$ sed -i '/^[^#].*текст/s/^/#/' файл
```

Answer (score 3):

Закомментировать строку с указанным номером (в данном случае вторую)

```
sed -i '2s/^/#/' ./file.txt
```

Раскомментировать обратно

```
sed -i '2s/^#//' ./file.txt
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем верный ответ на мой вопрос)
Как комментировать без проверки состояния строки я уже выяснил
sed -i -e 's/.*program3/# \0/' /file.txt

Comment: @Dok решение должно быть без if ?

Comment: @1d0 можно и без if, главное, чтоб не костыльно :)

Comment: @Dok: "не костыльно" просто удалить строчку, а не комментировать. "не костыльно" использовать git, augeas, puppet, etc по потребностям. Если sed выполняет работу в вашем случае, то это тоже "не костыльно".